# Store doesn't recognize my modules and shows no errors

Tags: module, vuex, store

I have a store.js file in my VueJS application but it is getting a tad too big so tried to create a few modules for it. However i am not sure what i am doing wrong since one of my modules files work normally while the other doesnt do anything and no errors are shows, my components simply don't show up.

All my module files are as follows:

```
const myModule= {
  state: {
    myState: false
  },
  mutations: {
    myMutation (state){
      return state.myState= true;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    myAction({ commit }) {
      // what i need to be done
    }
  },
  getters: {
    myState( state ) {
      return state.myState;
    }    
    }
  }

  export default myModule;
```

And i import them in my store.js file like this:

```
import myModule from '@/modules/myModule'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  modules: {
    loginModule
  },
```

and i've tried using their states and actions as follows

```
this.$store.dispatch('myAction').myModule
this.$store.getters['myModule/myState']
```

However only the first module file i created work while the others doesnt and all of them have the same structure and show no errors. Not sure what is wrong here.

EDIT: Apparently the actions are working but not my getters.

Comment: Can you check getters in Vue DevTools?

Comment: ill check. i was mostly using console.log() and apparently they are all being considered undefined for some reason.

Comment: they are being shown on vue devtools

Comment: including those that was not accessible?

Comment: yeah.
Bu i think i figured it out. apparently i didnt namespaced my module and therefore only the actions worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you don't need the store to be namespaced.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules

You most like want the modules to be namespaced.

Then you can easily access your properties using mapGetters,mapState,mapMutations,mapActions

Comment: i was able to not need to use map actions and etc, i jsut use 'moduleName/actionName instead.